# SQL:Remove duplicate Records ,If Date Difference between duplicate records is less than 30 days

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, duplicates

I want to delete duplicate records from a table (duplicate on the basic of `fkInvoiceId` and `fkcontractid`) if the `CreatedDate(another column)` difference between two duplicate records is less than 30 days.

```
WITH cte AS 
(   
    SELECT 
        Id,
        fkcontractid,
        fkInvoiceId,
        CreatedDate, 
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY fkcontractid, fkInvoiceId ORDER BY fkcontractid) AS [rn]   
    from mytable left join Invoice on Invoice.pkinvoiceid = mytable.fkinvoiceid
)   
delete tt from mytable tt inner join CTE as x on x.Id = tt.Id 
WHERE x.[rn] > 1;
```

Above query is deleting the duplicate records(`fkInvoiceId` and `fkcontractid`) but it is not taking difference of `Date(createdDate)`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Say you have 3 duplicates, each spaced 28 days apart. Which one(s) should be deleted and why?

Comment: If i have three duplicate then i want to retain the latest one.rest of the records should remove.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which tables each column comes from<sup>1</sup>, it's a little tricky to post the *exact* query you need, but something along these lines should work:

```
DELETE FROM t1
FROM mytable t1
    INNER JOIN
mytable t2
    ON
        t1.fkcontractid = t2.fkcontractid and
        t1.fkInvoiceId = t2.fkInvoiceId and
        t1.ID != t2.ID and --Assuming this is the primary key
        t1.CreatedDate < t2.CreatedDate and
        DATEADD(day,30,t1.CreatedDate) >= t2.CreatedDate
```

Hopefully, the logic is clear enough to read - for every row, we try to find another row (`ID`s don't match) with the same `fkcontractid` and `fkInvoiceId`, which occurs after the current row but only by as much as 30 days.

If we're successful in making that join, then this row (from `t1`) ought to be deleted.

---

<sup>1</sup>If `Invoice` is an important part of defining this query, it's unclear to me why it was being `LEFT JOIN`ed to rather than `INNER`, in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
delete tt from mytable tt inner join CTE as x on x.Id = tt.Id 
WHERE x.[rn] > 1 and datediff(day,tt.date_col,x.date_col)<30;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not helped in my case .It is still Deleting all duplicate records. Do not consider the date factor.